# Passing additional parameters from the parent URL to the iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to pass additional parameters from the parent URL to the iFrame. The scenario is that the parent site is `http://www.myparentsite.com/filter.html` and I would like to add an additional string `#!?filter=1` to the parent URL which will look like below link

```
http://www.myparentsite.com/filter.html#!?filter=1
```

Then after adding the additional string, the iFrame should inherit the same string that was added to the parent URL. The iFrame source should be `http://www.myiframe.com/filter.html#!?filter=1`

This is the sample javascript I did

```
<script>
    function newiframeSrc() {
       var url    = 'http://www.myiframe.com/filter.html';
       var params = window.location.search;
       var iframe_url = url+params;
       document.getElementById('iframe').src = iframe_url;
     }
</script>
```

Then the iFrame is

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src=" " style="width:100%;height:800px;"></iframe>
```

then I invoke this in the body tag

```html
<body onload="newiframeSrc()">
```

but the `src` is empty. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Where is `newiframeSrc` called?

Comment: Oh I put in in the body tag
<body onload="newiframeSrc()">

Comment: Is `#!?filter=1` being added before or after the `filter.html` loaded?

Comment: should be added after filter.html